# How to make browser auto flush?

Tags: php, browser, silverstripe

How do you make a browser auto flush a web page.  In Silverstripe CMS I have to manually flush a web page by appending ?flush in my URL. Anybody knows?

Comment: As flushing a SilverStripe page is really slow you really want to do this every time? I don't like when i hit "reload" and it flushes again. When do you need to flush? Normally only when you installed a module (then you'll need dev/build most of the time), when you changed some config vars, or when you added a new template file.

Comment: The Silverstripe flush you're referring to is a server side operation. The only way you could get a browser to automatically trigger it is to force it to add ?flush to the URL. Or, if you can make changes to the website, you could do it with some server side code. Perhaps you could clarify how and why you want to do it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php it's the solutuion.

Comment: That's not what SilverStripe does when it flushes. There it means "clear and rebuild the class manifest and other stuff (like templates)". So this answer is wrong, sorry.

Comment: See also: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/debugging/url_variable_tools/#templates

Comment: i second wmk, this is not the same as a silverstripe flush